# Magento 2.0 contact form not working on page CMS

Tags: magento-2.0, cms-pages

We recent;y migrated stores from magento v1, to v2.

We are having a problem getting the contact form to show up on one of the CMS pages.

I have tried a million variations of something like this.

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

However NOTHING shows up on the front end... just disappears. If you go to the www.stores.com/contact page there is the default contact form that shows up.

Whats the deal? How can I get that form on my CMS page, this used to be easy on v1

Thanks!
-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with this

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

**In Magento 2 If you want to add a block in cms page**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YoutTemplateFile.location].phtml"}}
```

**This is equivalent to Magento 1.X code**

```
{{ block type="core/template" template="YourtemplateFileLocation.phtml"}}
```